# How to set max date for jquery ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the jquery ui datepicker in my page and use two input elements id of 'startDate' and 'endDate'. My javascript has a function 'setRange()' in which min date is defined but I want to define max date that should be startDate+6 days only. I mean user must not select the date after 6 days of start date.

Please Help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I built something similar the other day. Basically you need to set the `maxDate` option on the `endDate` element, every time `startDate` is changed.

I like using moment.js for dates, since it allows you to do things like `date.add('days',6)`

Here's something to start you off:

```
$(function() {
  $('#start_date').change(function() {
    var start = $(this).val();
    var maxDate = new Date(); // I'll leave this to you...
    $('#end_date').datepicker('option','maxDate',maxDate);
  }).trigger('change'); // this sets the constraint on load, too
});
```